# HTML5 Canvas - Scaling relative to the center of an object without translating context

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working on a canvas game that has several particle generators. The particles gradually scale down after being created. To scale the particles down from their center points I am using the context.translate() method:

```
context.save();
context.translate(particle.x, particle.y);
context.translate(-particle.width/2, -particle.height/2);
context.drawImage(particle.image, 0, 0, particle.width, particle.height);
context.restore();
```

I've read several sources that claim the save(), translate() and restore() methods are quite computationally expensive. Is there an alternative method I can use?

My game is targeted at mobile browsers so I am trying to optimize for performance as much as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, just use `setTransform()` at the end instead of using save/restore:

```
//context.save();
context.translate(particle.x, particle.y);
context.translate(-particle.width/2, -particle.height/2);
context.drawImage(particle.image, 0, 0, particle.width, particle.height);
//context.restore();
context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);   // reset matrix
```

Assuming there are no other accumulated transform in use (in which case you could refactor the code to set absolute transforms where needed).

The numbers given as argument are numbers representing an identity matrix, ie. a reset matrix state.

This is much faster than the save/restore approach which stores and restores not only transform state, but style settings, shadow settings, clipping area and what have you.

You could also combine the two translation calls into a single call, and use multiply instead of divide (which is much faster at CPU level):

```
context.translate(particle.x-particle.width*0.5, particle.y-particle.height*0.5);
```

or simply use the x/y coordinate directly with the particle "shader" without translating at all.

Comment: Thank you - this small change increased mobile performance by 10-20fps. Much appreciated!

Comment: Upvote for significantly improving the questioners code with a good answer. I might add that if only translations are required then you might avoid context.translate entirely and just change the x,y coordinates.

Comment: I originally avoided it as I don't know the full scenario, but included it now so the option is more clear (one I personally would prefer - I'm using this in my own particle engine). Thanks markE. Also added more details.

Comment: Thanks for the update - I'm now using only x and y coordinates:  `context.drawImage(particle.image, particle.x-particle.width/2, particle.y-particle.height/2, particle.width, particle.height);` However now the rotation doesn't work. Is it safe to assume that this method only works with scale/translate?

Comment: @PeterRingelmann ah, if you have a rotation in between there you would need to separate them (translate to origin, rotate, translate back w/h of image). In this case you did everything correct (the rotate call wasn't in the original code snippet which is why I suggested condensing it).

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg Yes I should have probably included it...although I wanted to keep my snippet as concise as possible. I'm still quite new to stackoverflow :)   Thanks again for the advice